# How to add values temporary in md-list-item in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I'm trying to add some items in the list using material icon. Here items are adding permanently by `ng-click="contactDetails.contactModes.push(numbers);"`.

I have given 2 buttons on bottom of the card i.e save and discard. but problem is whenever material icon is clicked values get added in the list. Means No use of discard. My aim is to add values temporary on the list so that when ever user click on saved then only values get saved otherwise discarded.

Please suggest
**MY CODE:**

```
<md-list-item ng-show="showContactList" class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="numbers in contactList" ng-click="contactDetails.contactModes.push(numbers);">
    <i ng-show="numbers.type == 'sample'" class="material-icons md-avatar-icon">textsms</i>
    <i ng-show="numbers.type == 'CELL' || numbers.type == 'EXT'" class="material-icons md-avatar-icon">phone</i>
    <img class="pad-right-5 md-avatar dime-30" ng-show="numbers.type == 'PAGER'" src="assets/img/contact-pref/pager.png" width="26" style="width:30px;height:28px;margin-left: 5px;">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-class="{'md-offset': phone.options.offset }">
        <h3>  {{ numbers.type }} </h3>
        <p> {{ numbers.value }} </p>
    </div>
    <i class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right">add</i>
</md-list-item>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Temporary variable in controller

```
$scope.arrayText = [{
            "type": "sample",
            "value": "test"
        }];
```

and made following changes in the code to add temporary and finally using `contactDetails.contactModes = arrayText on ng-click added permanently using save button`

```
<md-list-item ng-show="showContactList" class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="numbers in contactList" >
        <i ng-show="numbers.type == 'TruliaCare'" class="material-icons md-avatar-icon">textsms</i>
        <i ng-show="numbers.type == 'CELL' || numbers.type == 'EXT'" class="material-icons md-avatar-icon">phone</i>
        <img class="pad-right-5 md-avatar dime-30" ng-show="numbers.type == 'PAGER'" src="assets/img/contact-pref/pager.png" width="26" style="width:30px;height:28px;margin-left: 5px;">
        <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-class="{'md-offset': phone.options.offset }">
        <h3>  {{ numbers.type }} </h3>
        <p> {{ numbers.value }} </p>
        </div>
        <i class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right" ng-click="arrayText.push(numbers);">add</i>
                  </md-list-item>
```